# Get string that is in between " " ( most appropriate method)

Tags: sql-server, substring

I'm working on extracting a string from a field and was hoping to see if there was a better way to do it.

This is what I currently have:

```
Select   ,Left(Right((SUBSTRING([TaskLink], CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]),
   CHARINDEX('" ',[TaskLink]) - CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]) + Len('" '))), LEN(SUBSTRING([TaskLink], CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]),
   CHARINDEX('" ',[TaskLink]) - CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]) + Len('" '))) - 1), len(Right((SUBSTRING([TaskLink], CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]),
   CHARINDEX('" ',[TaskLink]) - CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]) + Len('" '))), LEN(SUBSTRING([TaskLink], CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]),
   CHARINDEX('" ',[TaskLink]) - CHARINDEX('"', [TaskLink]) + Len('" '))) - 1)) -1)
From Table
```

This is what `TaskLink` has as values:

```
ef="00T200007jNUAR" target="_blank">
ef="02H00007QGNHUAP" target="_blank">
ef="00T0007RC5s6UAD" target="_blank">
```

This is what my output is (which is what I want):

```
00T200007jNUAR
02H00007QGNHUAP
00T0007RC5s6UAD
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the column value actually multiline as you have shown it?  Most likely, your solution cannot be much improved upon, as SQL Server does not have regex support, leaving the base string functions (what you are already using) as the only real option available.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: As an aside, it seems you are storing a *rendering* of data rather than data. Consider storing those values in a dedicated column and concatenating to get your sample text, either as you select or better in the app layer (if you have one).